# timescaledb-tune issue

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timescaledb

When i run command `$ sudo timescaledb-tune`
in my ubuntu 19.10 machine it prompt

could not execute `pg_config --version`: exit status 1

i also tried `$ sudo timescaledb-tune --conf-path=/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf`

but msg is same

can't understand what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timescale DB Tune uses `pg_config` to discover the version of Postgres running on the machine.

You can use the `-pg-config` flag to define the path to your pg_config or provide the Postgres version by using the `-pg-version` flag.

Here are some more details on the flags, which you can find by running

`$ timescaledb-tune -h`

```
 -pg-config string
        Path to the pg_config binary (default "pg_config")
  -pg-version string
        Major version of PostgreSQL to base recommendations on. Default is determined via pg_config. Valid values: 12, 11, 10, 9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to this since I ran into something very similar when I set up a custom data_directory path at /data/pgdata:

sudo timescaledb-tune -pg-config=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_config -pg-version=11 -conf-path=/data/pgdata

it finally worked:

```
Using postgresql.conf at this path:
/data/pgdata/postgresql.conf

Writing backup to:
/tmp/timescaledb_tune.backup202006231314

shared_preload_libraries needs to be updated
Current:
#shared_preload_libraries = ''
Recommended:
shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
```